# using "extends CAction" class of Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, magic-methods

in this tutorial of Yii framework 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#action

i want to put my Actions from a Controller to a separate action files
and as the instructions said "create a Action class"

and this is my action class file

```
class LoginAction extends CAction
{

    private $contents = array();
    public function run(){
        $loginmodel = new LoginForm;

        //answer ajax validating request
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form'){
            echo CActiveForm::validate($loginmodel);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }

        //collect user input data to do login
        if(isset($_POST["LoginForm"]))
        {
            $loginmodel->attributes = $_POST["LoginForm"];
            // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
            if($loginmodel->validate() && $loginmodel->login()){ //<--invoking here the login and validate function
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
            }
        }

        $this->contents["loginmodel"] =  $loginmodel;
        $this->render('index',$this->contents); 
    }    

}
```

and in my Controller

```
class SandboxController extends Controller{       
    public function actions(){
        // return external action classes, e.g.:
            return array(
            'authlog'=>'application.controllers.authentication.LoginAction',
            // page action renders "static" pages stored under 'protected/views/site/pages'
            // They can be accessed via: index.php?r=site/page&view=FileName
            'page'=>array(
                'class'=>'CViewAction',
            ),
        );   
    }
}
```

and i browse the separate action controller using

> http://localhost/mysite/index.php/sandbox/authlog/login

and my error is

> LoginAction and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named
>   "render".

do i went wrong on something? thanks.

here is the stacktrace

> CException LoginAction and its behaviors do not have a method or
>   closure named "render".
>
> D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\framework\base\CComponent.php(266)
>
> 254     public function __call($name,$parameters) 255     { 256
>   if($this->_m!==null) 257         { 258             foreach($this->_m
>   as $object) 259             { 260
>   if($object->getEnabled() && method_exists($object,$name)) 261
>   return call_user_func_array(array($object,$name),$parameters); 262
>   } 263         } 264         if(class_exists('Closure', false) &&
>   $this->canGetProperty($name) && $this->$name instanceof Closure) 265
>   return call_user_func_array($this->$name, $parameters); 266
>   throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','{class} and its behaviors do not
>   have a method or closure named "{name}".', 267
>   array('{class}'=>get_class($this), '{name}'=>$name))); 268     } 269 
>   270     /** 271      * Returns the named behavior object. 272      *
>   The name 'asa' stands for 'as a'. 273      * @param string $behavior
>   the behavior name 274      * @return IBehavior the behavior object, or
>   null if the behavior does not exist 275      */ 276     public
>   function asa($behavior) 277     { 278         return
>   isset($this->_m[$behavior]) ? $this->_m[$behavior] : null; Stack Trace
>
> ## 0
>
> - D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\protected\controllers\authentication\LoginAction.php(26):
>     CComponent->__call("render", array("index", array("loginmodel" =>
>     LoginForm)))
>
>   ## 1
> - D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\protected\controllers\authentication\LoginAction.php(26):
>     LoginAction->render("index", array("loginmodel" => LoginForm))
>
>   ## 2
> - D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\framework\web\actions\CAction.php(75): LoginAction->run()
>
>   ## 3
> - D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\framework\web\CController.php(309): CAction->runWithParams(array("login" => ""))
>
>   ## 4
> - D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\framework\web\CController.php(287): CController->runAction(LoginAction)
>
>   ## 5
> - D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\framework\web\CController.php(266): CController->runActionWithFilters(LoginAction, array())
>
>   ## 6
> - D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(276): CController->run("authlog")
>
>   ## 7
> - D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(135): CWebApplication->runController("sandbox/authlog/login")
>
>   ## 8
> - D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\framework\base\CApplication.php(162): CWebApplication->processRequest()
>
>   ## 9
> - D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\index.php(13): CApplication->run() 2012-03-05 09:37:43 Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21
>     OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 Yii
>     Framework/1.1.10

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace associated with the error.

Comment: just added the error stacktrace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with this line of code:

```
$this->render('index',$this->contents);
```

This would be fine if it were inside a controller, but once the code is moved inside a dedicated action class there's no longer a `render` method to be called on `$this`, hence the error.

You simply need to get a reference to the controller first and call `render` on that:

```
$controller=$this->getController();
$controller->render('index',$this->contents);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your action to access any controller method:

```
//MyAction.php
<?php

class MyAction extends CAction
{
    public function render($view, array $options=array())
    {
        $this->getController()->render($view, $options);
    }
}

//LoginAction.php:
<?php

class LoginAction extends MyAction
{
(...)
```